# c++ popen, fgetc, fscanf, impossible to read a line, non error

Tags: c++, popen, fgets, scanf

I can open a process 
(i perform a shell script whose output is 
1443772262175; URL filter 
1443772267339; URL blocked ...) with popen, no problem

but after impossible to read it
I try fscanf, fgets(buff_out, sizeof(buff_out)-1, pf)

```
int lineno = 0;
if ((pf = popen(files_to_open, "r")) != NULL) 
 while (!feof(pf))
{
    fscanf(pf, "%s %s", buffer, afficher);
    message << buffer << " " << afficher ;
}
or while (fgets(buff_out, sizeof(buff_out)-1, pf) != NULL) {
}
```

i try with a program test it works fine but with a program more complexe (parallel) that i can't debug (the programm complexe) it fails no error just nothing to scan or read

Should i abandon popen?

Thanks for help

Comment: How can you tell that there is no error? Since you ignored the result of `fscanf()` any error reported is clearly not looked at.

Comment: I think it is because permission file

Comment: you right  there are errors i didn't see